# Return value of server.accept() while waiting for connection

Tags: java, sockets, networking

What does the `server.accept()` method return when no new socket is formed, i.e., when no new connection is made? Is it possible to go to next line of code while `sever.accept()` is waiting for a new connection?

Comment: It *doesn't* return, in blocking mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to do something while the server is waiting for a connection you can use multiple threads. In a single-threaded application you cannot call a function and continue with your work without waiting it to return: either you are waiting for the server to accept a connection, or you are doing other computations.

A possible alternative to threads is setting [the `SO_TIMEOUT` socket option](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/ServerSocket.html#setSoTimeout%28int%29) on the server socket. This makes the call to `accept` throw an exception if a connection is not received within the timeout, allowing you to go to the next line.

For example:

```
ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(8989);
ss.setSoTimeout(10000); // 10 seconds
Socket clientSocket;
try {
    clientSocket = ss.accept();
    // process connection from client
} catch (SocketTimeoutException ste) {
    // connection was not received,
    // do something else
}
```

Another alternative is using non-blocking IO and the [`Selector`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/channels/Selector.html) class.  Here's an  [example of a non-blocking socket server](http://www.cordinc.com/blog/2010/08/java-nio-server-example.html) written this way.

Answer (score 0):

No. server.accept() is a blocking method and it will wait.

From the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/ServerSocket.html#accept%28%29)

> Listens for a connection to be made to this socket and accepts it. The
>   method blocks until a connection is made.